# Google assistant notification

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

Refer me to some ready made example of google assistant notification, I'm a tech guy I have already developed app with dialogflow(donot support notification yet), I have both google home and mobile assistant, just want to see google action notification in action.

Comment: You can find information https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates There are some step by step tutorials to enable different type of notifications. If you read under 'Push notifications' you can see one example there and if you follow it you can see it in action for yourself.

Comment: I need step by step guide or running example

Answer (score 1):

There's this [very detailed guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) by Google with ready made code that you can easily adapt to your needs.

It offers code for Dialogflow as well as for the plain ActionsSDK.

Basically the steps are:

- Ask for permission
- React to it in your fulfillment code (confirming the user's decision)
- Notifying Google's backend when it should send a notification to the user (you need a JSON web token). This last step has to be done on some backend which knows about when to send notifications

Those steps are outlined in more detail on the linked site and there's also described how to obtain the token.

Comment: Hi @Wolfram Rittmeyer in my case completed all the steps but i got error on sending notification 
Error Cannot read property 'access_token'
 of undefined

Comment: As this exception says, some object has not be defined (which is even worse than it being null). Check if all objects have been set up correctly.

Comment: i'm Getting  error : URL is not a constructor in jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens))

Comment: Have a look exactly at your code. Must be something wrong when initializing JWT. The message sounds like you did the constructing wrong (the line above authorize).

Comment: here is my full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55371048/access-token-undefined